# Hibernate: findById vs findAllById, what to use for list of ids and non-nested for loops

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, nested-loops, jparepository

1. I have a list of ids that are associated with objects to fetch. I need to process
   each object after fetching them.

   Should I get the list of objects using findAllById, so there will be one DB call and
   then process the result using for loop?

   OR

   Should I run the for loop for ids, and process each object using findById? Which
   seems bad as it will do multiple DB calls.
2. Is multiple non-nested for loop better than multiple DB calls?

Comment: findAllByIds slower that findById in cicle why? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75383453/why-findallbyid-is-slower-than-findbyid-in-a-loop-jpa-hibernate-jav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Its better using findAllByIds because one DB call and if you want to process each data, you can achieve that by doing loop/foreach/stream
2. Yes, because it would decrease the minimum of error by creating DB call.